# Retrieving a date from Firestore in Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

From the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types) on saving data of supported types, I red:

```
var docData = {
    //...
    dateExample: new Date("December 10, 1815"),
    //...
    }
};
db.collection("data").doc("one").set(docData).then(function() {
console.log("Document successfully written!");
});
```

This is what I use in my Cloud Functions to save various dates to Firestore.
It works great !

My problem comes when I need to retrieve those dates and post them as String to a third party API.

As far as I understood, in Firebase/Firestore, dates are stored as a Unix Timestamp.

I couldn't find anywhere (firebase doc, stackoverflow ...) how to convert it properly to a String.

I tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp){
    var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var year = a.getFullYear();
    var month = months[a.getMonth()];
    var date = a.getDate();
    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    var sec = a.getSeconds();
    var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;
    return time;
  }

admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get()
    .then( (doc) => {
        const user = doc.data();
        const birthDate = user.birthDate;
        const birthDateString = timeConverter(birthDate);
        console.log(`birthDateString =${birthDateString}`);
     // "birthDateString = NaN undefined NaN NaN:NaN:NaN" 
     });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you can use `toDate()` to convert the Firebase timestamp to a `Date` object and then use the `Date`'s object method `toDateString()` to convert it to a String.

```
const birthDate = user.birthDate.toDate();
const birthDateString = birthDate.toDateString();
```

You can also check out [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), it helps a lot when dealing with Dates and displaying them.

Comment: Many thanks, it works ! Except that I dont get the format I am looking for (2019-01-17 19:30), but this is another question that I'll try to investigate by myself now...

Comment: That's why I recommended Moment.js, with it you can display in many different formats. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to : how do I convert a unix timestamp to a human readable date?

There are several ways to do this but one of the easiest is to use

```
var readableData = new Date(doc.data().myUnixTimestamp).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
```

There are options for all locales. See MDN's [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Comment: Thanks very much, but it doesn't seams to be working. I get "birthDate.toLocaleDateString is not a function". Are dates really stored as Unix timestamp ? This is maybe the question...

Comment: How the dates are stored is up to you. I choose to use standard unix timestamps (generated in JavaScript using `var created = Date.now()`.  Note that the `.toLocaleDateString("en-US");` only accepts `Date` objects, so you must first parse the timestamp as a Date object, the `new Date()` part mentioned above.